# C# DLL Message Box

Tags: c#, dll, messagebox

Is it possible to have a C# DLL open a message box? Like in a WinForm:

```
MessageBox.Show("Message");
```

I relise that DLL's can't be executed directly but what if it were to be injected into a process to be run, then it could show the message box (if it's possible).

Comment: Do you specifically want to use System.Windows.Forms, or do you want it to be a interface IMessageBox and you inject an implementation when you use the Dll?

Answer (score 11):

Step1: Click on Add Reference. Under .NET, Select `System.Windows.Forms` and click ok!

Step2: use namespace `using System.Windows.Forms;`